# how to get acess token for google without user login

Tags: google-authentication, google-admin-sdk

I use Web server applications to get acess token. It's work but need to acess user login and  consent page.
Is any way that get the acess token doesn't need user login to the web site?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have OAuth integrated, you would need the user to grant access to the application, that would be the consent the user need to approve at least once, because the app would do the work on behalf of the user who give its consent for the app to "represent" him in a way.

Once user grant its consent, there is a consent token that the app should use to get the Refresh and Access token.

- Access Token has expiration time, then the app would have to generate a new Access token.
- Refresh Token is only used to generate a new Access Token, and that would not requier a new user consent.

Basically, the user need to give its consent once, and then your app would have to store the Refresh token to generate new Access Tokens when they expire, there is no way to generate the tokens without the user consent, but that would be needed only once.